# Reset column to default value

Tags: list, column, sharepoint-server, yes-no-field

Given is a list with a yes/no column. Default value of this column is "no". What is the most efficient way to reset all items in the column to "no".

I definitely don't want to solve the problem by using a foreach loop. At the moment I am deleting the whole column and create a new one with the same name and default value.

Comment: How many existing items you have in your list?

Comment: There is no OOTB way to achieve this. Existing items do not get default value untill you update them.

Comment: About 500 items...

Comment: @harshalgite So what would you say is the best way in my case?

Comment: You can increase item limit of view to 100 items and then use quick edit to drag the default value right till the end. NOTE: if any workflow is attached to item updation then it will get triggered

Comment: You can use **Quick edit** and select the first value to **No** then select it and slide down to apply for the rest of items.